# C# code using sonar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sonar-runner

I am using .net framework 4.6.2 and visual studio 2015.I have written sample c# project and tried analyzing with sonar, I am able to run sonarqube successfully but after that in sonar server the result is empty.
find below detail description of what I have done:

1. Downloaded and installed sonarqube and kept in
   C:\Softwares\sonarqube-6.7.4
2. Downloaded and installed scanner ,
   C:\Softwares\sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0
3. Added the path variable value
   in Environment variable as :C:\Softwares\sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0\bin
4. Then run the start sonar command
   from:C:\Softwares\sonarqube-6.7.4\bin\windows-x86-64 which shows
   process is up, SonarQube is up .
5. My sample solution path is :
   C:\Softwares\c# sample\sample Also added sonar-project file in the
   same path which contains project details such as path, key ,port,
   version, language.
6. In the cmd window reach out to the solution path and hit sonar-scanner command

which shows Execution Success 
after checking http://localhost:9000/projects?sort=-analysis_date shows zero bugs,zero Vulnerabilities and 0 code smells with passed solution name.

Can someone have an idea what is wrong or missing in this ?
adding the screenshot of cmd prompt

[sonar-qube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYCQz.png)
[sonar scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAd3E.png)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Scanner for MSBuild to analyze C# (or VB.NET), not the Scanner CLI.
The documentation is [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).

Comment: However, I have downloaded MSBuild version:4.3.1.1372 and kept at C:\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner 
 also the sonarQube 7.2 is in the same path. My sample solution is in path : C:\c# sample. 
 1)After running startsonar.bat file sonar qube is up.

Comment: 2) then in the root directory of solution I have run C:\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"samplesolution" /n:"ConsoleApplication" /v:"1.0"   - which is successful. 
3) the 2 nd command:"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild -whihc is also succeed

Comment: 4) Then end command:C:\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end - which shows warning with execution success 
 ...Now when I check the sonar server at http:\\locolhost:9000 , 
Its shows project name but with zero details of bugs, Vulnerabilities,Code Smells.

Comment: What warning appears in the end step?

If you go to the SonarQube UI and browse to the Code tab for the project, does it show the files in the project and the lines of code numbers? If so, then the scanner output is being correctly processed and passed to SonarQube, so check that your sample project does have code issues.

Comment: Hi,It shows file but the lines of code number is zero. Attaching the link for detail message scareenshot : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qq4O2ASjRmQzMz4KLqVtdYU9YSJIeB8G.....Thanks

Comment: I have only one file is solution with simple hello worldprogram// A Hello World! program in C#.
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            string name = "abc";
            string password = "#$bndfjgng";
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}